# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function when using typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a basic example with `typeahead.js`

I have included files in the following order.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/typeahead.js"></script>
```

(application js contains jquery)

Following is my initialisation code.

```
$('#custom-templates .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'best-pictures',
  display: 'value',
  source: '/search',
  templates: {
    empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
        'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: function(data) {
    return '<p><strong>' + data.name + '</strong> – ' + data.id + '</p>';
}
  }
});
```

and the markup is

```
<div id="custom-templates">
            <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Oscar winners for Best Picture">
            </div>
```

But in the console i'm getting the following error.

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function when using typeahead.js` and there are no other errors too.
What am i doing wrong ?

`typeahead.js` has also been loaded properly when i check the page source.

Comment: can you add a FIDDLE ?

Comment: Make sure you're not loading multiple copies of jQuery.

Comment: How will i be able to check that ? To my knowledge i have included one in the application.js , nothing after that.

Comment: Make sure that your `js` scripts run after DOM been loaded